# Cannot install Docker on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation, 17.10, docker

So, a whole day has been spend trying to install docker. This is the error i keep getting. I used the official approach from docker, and also tried the digital ocean installation guide.

```
Setting up docker-ce (18.04.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu) ...
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status docker.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-04-19 17:33:13 GMT; 10ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 6283 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) ## i suspect this line in service file
 Main PID: 6283 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CPU: 201ms

Apr 19 17:33:13 sav-subsystems systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 19 17:33:13 sav-subsystems systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After restarting and journaling the error:
I got this ->

```
-- Unit docker.socket has begun starting up.
Apr 19 17:37:30 sav-subsystems systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Apr 19 17:37:30 sav-subsystems systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 19 17:37:30 sav-subsystems systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Apr 19 17:37:30 sav-subsystems systemd[1]: docker.socket: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 19 17:37:30 sav-subsystems systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 19 17:37:30 sav-subsystems systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I also download a debian package and installed, it also failed.

Comment: I think it's not configured properly seeing this: `dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure)`, so do `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and see if it's up with `systemctl status docker`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to install it using this page steps: https://gist.github.com/levsthings/0a49bfe20b25eeadd61ff0e204f50088

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88

sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty stable"

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

Comment: After this approach i have to use `sudo docker .. `

Comment: @saviour123 `sudo usermod -aG docker <your_username>` should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if the docker -ce was installed and service is running .. sometimes if you try multiple installations,, it may throw this type of error.
If so, uninstall and try to install following steps from [this tutorial](https://crunchytechbytz.wordpress.com/2018/06/25/how-to-install-docker-in-ubuntu-18-04/) -

Essentially you will run following commands -

1. install the dependencies  first

   ```
    sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
   ```
2. add the GPG key for the official Docker repository to the system:

   ```
   curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
3. Add the Docker repository in sources.list.d to APT sources using below command

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] 
   https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable edge"
   ```
4. verify if you are able to install Docker from Docker repository

   ```
   apt-cache policy docker-ce
   ```
5. Finally,  install Docker CE package with below command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce
   ```

Voila, you have installed Docker-CE. you can verify installation by checking the version of  docker-ce installed

```
docker --version
```